# Fresh install of 19.10, had some issues around encrypton and partitioning

Tags: boot, partitioning, system-installation, encryption

Ubuntu 19.10  wouldn't let me select the right disk for manual partitioning in the live usb (on the actual resizing selection page it only shows the windows HD with no option to select anything else), so I let ubuntu auto guide the partitioning of the new drive.

When I booted in there are no root or swap partitions. Just boot and one big encrypted volume.

Is this to be expected? Shouldn't I need the other two traditional partitions?

Comment: Ubuntu 18.04 LTS & later can use swap files, so no separate swap partition is required (this is the default).   The one partition will be your / (root) partition, it's not normal to have /root (root user's directory) is a separate partition. After swap (no longer default) the other common partition is /home/ which is not created by default (more partitions just complicate things for the average user - there are reasons you want them, but the users that want or need it usually use Manual Partitioning (something-else) & create what they want/need themselves.   What you have is expected.

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu 18.04 LTS & later can use swap files, so no separate swap partition is required (this is the default).

The one partition will be your / (root) partition, it's not normal to have /root (root user's directory) in a separate partition (so I'm not sure what you mean by root)

After swap (*no longer default*) the other common partition is /home/ (for user files) which is **not** created by default; more partitions just complicate things for the average user - there are reasons you want them, but the users that want or need it usually use *Manual Partitioning* (*something-else*) & create what they want/need themselves.

What you have is expected.

FYI: The following is an example of a QA-install (quality assurance testing) done yesterday of Lubuntu 20.04 showing the partitions I got for default (*no encryption for that install, full disk & replace existing (prior Xubuntu 20.04) system using *defaults* (which may be different to your `ubiquity` install of Ubuntu 19.10 but will be **very** close). FYI: I added a load of [backup] files to it which is why used space is so high). *Modern Lubuntu uses Qt which is why the KDE Partition Manager*

[image]